# Making pattern using loops Java

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm supposed to create some pattern - somewhat triangular - using for loop based on given number n.

For example, if given number n is 3, the pattern should be something like this :

```
  **
 *##*
*####*
```

And below is the piece of code I'm currently working on now.

```
public static void patterPrinters(int n) {
  for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
    for ( int x = n; x > k + 1; x--) {
      System.out.print(" ");
      }

    for ( int z = n - k; z <= n; z++) {
      System.out.print("**");
      }
      System.out.print("\n");
      }
  }
}
```

So far, I was able to make a similar shape, but of course, it is filled with stars (*) without the number signs(#) in between them. Like :

```
  **
 ****
******
```

Could someone give me a hint as what I'm supposed to do from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 public static void patterPrinters(int n) {
    int i,j,k;
    for( i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
      for(k=0;k<((n-1)-i);k++)
      {
        System.out.print(" ");
      }
      System.out.print("*");
      for(j=0;j<(i*2);j++)
      {
        System.out.print("#")
      }
      System.out.print("*\n");
    }
}
```

check this out.
All the Best.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

If you managed to print the correct shape, but with `*` only, you can easily fix this by printing a single `*` at the start and end of each row, and between them print x-2 `#`s, where x is the number of `*` you currently print in each row.

Answer (score 0):

public static void patterPrinters(int n)

```
{
    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) 
    {
        for (int x = n; x > k + 1; x--) 
        {
          System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.print("*");
        for (int col = 0; col < k; col++) 
        {
          System.out.print("##");
        }
        System.out.print("*\n");
      }
}
```